# Do http proxies have some request memory?

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy, cache-control

Imagine we have http client, some proxy and web-server that serves as backend. The proxy is configured to cache the responses of the backend.

A request arrives, the proxy transfers it to the backend, the latter responses, the proxy caches the response and sends it to the client.

Imagine the backend has set some cache-related headers in its response to the proxy's request. For example:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache         (or)
Cache-Control: max-age=100000   (or)
Expires: 'Next Friday'
```

1. **A question is:** Will the next request from the client be processed by the proxy in compliance with that headers?
2. **Another flavour of the question:** Is there a way for a proxy to understand that the resource is stale, except for its own static resource-lifetime settings?
3. **Third variation:** Can the client force the proxy to load the fresh resource version if the proxy's version of the resource is not considered stale by the proxy?

My question may look a little bit overgeneralized, not specific enough. I'll try to address this issue by working with **browser + nginx proxy + nginx web-server** setup. If my setup works correctly, in case some resource has been cached by proxy and nginx's proxy_cache_valid timeout is still on - nothing can prevent the proxy from serving a stale response; whatever I do the requests do not hit the backend.

It looks like nginx decides whether the cache is stale only basing on proxy_cache_valid setting, and the headers of backend's response do not matter at all. I'm wondering whether my guess is correct and whether it can be incorrect for some other http proxy setups, serving as reverse proxy such as nginx, office network internal proxy such as squid, internet public proxy.